# Information about the office of the Chief Rabbi of England

Tags: rabbis, current-events, organizations

Who determines the Chief Rabbi of England?

- Is he picked by a general vote of all Shul attendees in Great Brittan?
- Is he picked by a committee picked by boards of different Shuls?

What are his powers?

Does he have a monopoly on Kashrus/Weddings/Divorces (Like in Israel)?

Comment: I picked current events since the elections of the Chief Rabbi of GB is coming up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.thejc.com/news/uk-news/53087/who-will-pick-new-chief-rabbi) explains how the chief Rabbi is chosen and what are his powers.

> Broadly speaking, the job combines two different roles. One is
>   ambassador of Judaism to the outside world; the other is "rabbi of
>   rabbis", the senior rabbi of the United Synagogue and other central
>   Orthodox communities. While the roles are not mutually exclusive, the
>   question is which will be given greater emphasis.
>
> In theory, constitutionally, the chief rabbi is the supreme authority
>   of the United Synagogue, and the Beth Din is there to advise him. In
>   practice, it is the Beth Din that has been seen increasingly to call
>   the religious shots, and the current Chief Rabbi has been accused of
>   yielding too much ground to it.
>
> His preference was to appoint a small working group of around seven
>   people who would draw up a shortlist and interview the candidates.
>   Their recommendation would be then submitted for approval to a larger
>   representative group of around 30, made up of delegates from various
>   constituencies under the aegis of the chief rabbi, but also possibly
>   from outside. Mr Pack proposes to chair both groups himself.
>
> When Lord Sacks was appointed, the decision was taken by a body known
>   as the Chief Rabbinate Council, composed of around 200 members
>   although a smaller selection committee of 35 was set up to recommend a
>   name.
>
> The council was superseded in 2002 by the much smaller Chief Rabbinate
>   Trust, comprising three United Synagogue officers, three other
>   trustees nominated by the United Synagogue and three trustees
>   representing regional and other communities.

Comment: I believe the previous chief rabbi, Lord Jacobovits, described the difference between his position and the Israeli chief rabbinate as: "My job has influence but no power; his has power but no influence."

Answer (score 2):

You can find details of the process here: http://www.chiefrabbi.org/CR_Application.aspx.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for the answer, which would be improved [if you'd summarize the relevant parts of that page](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76) instead of merely linking to it. Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1279), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.